# Nothing happened when I installed auto-complete-clang for c++ autocomplete in emacs

Tags: c++, emacs, autocomplete, clang

I have just downloaded [`auto-complete-clang.el`](https://github.com/brianjcj/auto-complete-clang). After I have installed and reopen emacs with a `.cpp` file. It seems that nothing happened. There is no code autocomplete at all. My auto-complete and yasnippet work fine. I also have clang and clang++ in my path.

The following is my `.emacs` file about this part:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "/Users/xinqiang/.emacs.d/")
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "/Users/xinqiang/.emacs.d//ac-dict")
(ac-config-default)

(require 'auto-complete-clang)
```

Could anyone can give me any help? Thanks a lot!

Comment: The emacs code mentioned on the linked site, labelled with "install" seems to be a bit longer

Comment: I have also pasted the emacs code in the install section into my .emacs file. But it didn't work either.